# Wrong path when dockerizing a Vue Php

Tags: node.js, docker, vue.js

I am pretty new to Docker, so in order to train it a bit i would like to fully dockerize my app. App consists of 3 main folders:

Folder - backend - where i have php backend of my app

Folder - frontend - where i have vue frontend of my app

File docker-compose.yml - nothing to add i guess :D

Folder - docker -> where i have folders with Dockerfiles for each system -> vue,php,nginx

Dockerfile for nginx:

```
FROM nginx:1.17.8-alpine

# Copy the public directory
COPY . /app/

# Copy the nginx config file
COPY ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Dockerfile for php:

```
FROM php:7.4.3-fpm-alpine3.11


RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

COPY ./sunday_league_backend/ /app

VOLUME ["/app"]
```

And Dockerfile for vue:

```
FROM node:14.5.0-alpine

WORKDIR /sunday_league_frontend

# Install VueCLI
RUN npm install -g @vue/cli

# Copy project files
COPY . sunday_league_frontend

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install


# Expose the app port
EXPOSE 8080

# Start the app
CMD ["npm", "run", "serve"]
```

The server and backend part of code are working great. However when i try to add frontend to it i`m getting errno error. It says that the path is wrong `npm ERR! path /sunday_league_frontend/package.json`

PS What i discovered by trying multiple configurations if i switch Dockerfile for vue like this:

```
FROM node:14.5.0-alpine


RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

# Install VueCLI
RUN npm install -g @vue/cli

# Copy project files
COPY . /app/

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install


# Expose the app port
EXPOSE 8080

# Start the app
CMD ["npm", "run", "serve"]
```

And move all files from frontend file into main app folder, so it would be on same level as Folders for backend, docker and docker-compose.yml it will work just great. However it makes the architecture of files look terrible. What am i still missing :/
docker-compose file for better visualisation:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/nginx/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    volumes:
      - .:/app/
    links:
      - php
      - vue

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/php/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/app/

  vue:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/vue/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '8081:8080'
    volumes:
      - .:/app/
```

[image: Files structure]

Comment: if you want to run npm install, you need to make sure you have the package.json in the filesystem. So copy it before install, to the right location.

Comment: _`COPY . sunday_league_frontend`_  there's your problem. You're already in the `/sunday_league_frontend` working directory. Your `COPY` command will be creating another directory `/sunday_league_frontend/sunday_league_frontend`. Just use `COPY . .`

Comment: Sadly it does not help. Should i also change something in my docker-compose file? I added more info to main post, for better visualisation of my problem

Comment: Ohh it does work, just forgot that i have everything wrapped into /app so it must look like this: ```WORKDIR /app/sunday_league_frontend/``` Thanks a lot. Do you maybe have some tips whether it is now done in correct way. It do works, but should it look like this in some commercial project?